# C# NAudio.dll implemented but not working

Tags: c#, naudio

i was using NAudio.dll with no problems on the old PC but now on this one i can't use it anymore.......
I installed it with the NuGet( both version since the last one doesn't work with framework 4.7.2) on Visual Studio 2019 but when i wrote the basic code to get sound output ecc..

```
var deviceEnum = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
var devices = deviceEnum.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.All, DeviceState.Active).ToList();
```

and try to compile, i got this error:
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUyqq.png)

Am i stupid or something?? I'm getting so maaaad!

|||SOLVED|||

For others with the same problem just Ensure `using NAudio.CoreAudioApi;`
and `using System.Linq;` are present.

ty Hans Passant :)

Comment: Ensure `using NAudio.CoreAudioApi;` and `using System.Linq;` are present.

Comment: Ty! Now is working!, but before on the old project i wasn't using it and it was working anyways for some reason...